# List of MSBuild built-in variables

Tags: msbuild

How can I get a list of built-in MSBuild variables?

I need to know how to determine the current project's csproj name, and thought it might be useful to know what else I can find out in MSBuild.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Comprehensive lists from Microsoft Docs (New Docs):

- [Common macros for MSBuild commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties)
- [MSBuild reference for .NET SDK projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#assemblyinfo-properties)

Comprehensive lists from MSDN (Legacy Docs):

- [MSBuild reserved properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties)
- [Common MSBuild properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)
- [Macros for Build Commands and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx)

Other useful lists:

- [Well-known item metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx)
- [MSBuild special characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx)

First link shows the MSBuild property for project name:

> **MSBuildProjectName** The file name of the project file without the file
> name extension

Comment: I would also include https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#assemblyinfo-properties. Those properties are quite useful when migrating to the new csproj format.

Answer (score 11):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs(loband).aspx

Comment: This is a link to the list of macros mentioned in the later question. I believe these are properties set by VS, so note that if building from command line - these values won't be set.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a pretty thorough list: *[Common macros for MSBuild commands and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019)*

Answer (score 4):

These properties can also be defined by 3rd-party tools so to get the complete list I just use (in a C++ project for example): Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> then on the Output or Intermediate Directory drop down choose Edit... and you should see a list of all defined properties.

Answer (score 2):

There are also Agent and Build predefined variables for pipelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml. These are the variables I was looking for when I came across this article, so I thought I'd pass the link along when I finally found them.

Answer (score 1):

I would also include a list of List of [Common Properties and Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) for MSBuild.

Also, the properties depend on which version of MSBuild you are using. There are 3 versions.