# Handling images and sound files for a simple C++ project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am new to Visual Studio, and I am trying to figure out the best way to organize my projects.

I am writing an application using the sfml library, and I have various resources (images/sounds) that I am using. I dropped these into the project folder, and everything works fine when I launch my application from Visual Studio.

I am wondering though, how does this translate to when a program is deployed? If I go into my solution's debug folder, and try launching the exe, it is unable to locate any of the resource files. Am I suppose to tell Visual Studio to copy files to an appropriate directory, and if so how?

Thanks for any advice or links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For slightly more complicated "deployment" scenario, you can use [post-build scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) to copy the correct files into the output directory and even package it into a zip file, for example.

If you find yourself writing more than one page of batch you may want to consider the options below, because batch is a PITA to debug.

Recent MSVS project files are actually [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) files (just open the `.vcxproj` file in Notepad or Vim). For instance you can use the [Copy task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx), invoke arbitrary programs using the [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx), etc. It can be a bit more sophisticated than the batch script in post-build scripts. MSBuild 4 can use [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) making it quite expressive. [Useful reference if you do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452962/list-of-msbuild-built-in-variables)

For a "full blown" project, you'll want to roll a dedicated build system using a dedicated MSBuild file, [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) or even higher level wrappers like [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/).

As a less popular alternative, in a previous project I built a small dedicated "builder" .exe project in the solution and have other projects depend on it. Then in the post-build scripts of the other projects I just invoke the builder projects with arguments to make it perform certain tasks. The advantage is that you can write C# (or F# or VB.NET) and not have to fight the build system (as much) and I think it works quite well for small-mid sized projects.

Answer (score 1):

for my project, I direct everything into one directory.
Go to ur project configuration, change `General->Output directory`, `General->intermediate directory`, and `Debugging->Working directory` to one directory. The reason you cannot locate the resource files is because the debug directory is not the same as the output directory.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you have the debug and release configurations put their files in the same location?

Comment: no, if you look at the top left side of the property page, there is different configuration for debug and release build.