# Can I use different reference for DLL in csproj for local and TFS build?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, projects-and-solutions

Is there a way to specify in .csproj file, to use different reference for DLL when my project is build localy and when build on TFS?

I want to share some DLLs between more solutions (do not want to copy DLLs to each solution's lib directory).

My local source structure is as follows

```
.\TfsProject
    .\lib
        MyShared.Dll
    .\Solution1
        .\Project1
        .\Project2
    .\Solution2
        .\Project1
        .\Project2
```

All Projects share relative path to `MyShared.Dll`

```
<HintPath>..\..\lib\MyShared.Dll</HintPath>
```

My problem arise on TFS Build server, where is source structure different from the local one.

I have tried to update .csproj files to use conditional statements, to use different `HintPath` localy and on TFS build server when referencig the `MyShared.Dll`. My condition is as follows

```
<Choose>
  <!-- Local HintPath -->
  <When Condition="'$(SourceDir)' == ''">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference ...>
        <HintPath>..\..\lib\MyShared.Dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <!-- TFS Specific HintPath -->
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference ...>
        <HintPath>$(SourceDir)\..\_build\lib\MyShared.Dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Localy build passes, but I get `The type or namespace name could not be found` error on TFS build because it cannot find `MyShared.Dll`.

Any idea how can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my issue by specifying `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` and adjusting `HintPath` instead of `$(SourceDir)`. Seems that `$(SourceDir)` was not recognized by build server as valid variable within .csproj.

List of available build variables:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309(v=vs.120).aspx

This question also helped:

[List of MSBuild built-in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452962/list-of-msbuild-built-in-variables)

Answer (score 1):

I would configure the workspace mapping for the TFS Build to match what you have locally, so the relative paths can resolve properly on the build server.

Comment: This was my original plan, but got an error when second solution was build. Build wanted to re-download shared lib folder, but it was already assigned to workspace created for solution 1, during first build.

Comment: make sure all your workspace mappings are mapped to something under $(SourceDir) and that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to avoid to have shared lib in each solution. I want it to be in one folder in source control and all the solutions should reference it. 

I would still need to distinguish, if the build runs locally (reference to shared folder is used, which is outside of $(SourceDir)) or on build server, shared lib can be mapped under $(SourceDir), but different HintPath need to be used in .csproj. 

But finally figured it out using $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) variable. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.