# Windows Work flow for TFS Build process Tutorial

Tags: workflow, build-process, tfsbuild

Is there any tutorial which is used to create a build Windows work flow for the project solution which has many projects. Needed to create a custom build using the Work flow.

When i used the default template for our solution, the build is getting drop for every project in a single release folder. Our solution has around 70 projects and all the build is dropping into a single folder. How do we customize to  make the build of each project has its respective release folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ALM Rangers put out [the best tutorial](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/) I know of for customizing builds in TFS.

I work for a large enterprise with MANY TFS builds and we have always avoided changing the build process template.  I would challenge you to look at other TFS extension points instead, for example

- pre/post build/test PowerShell scripts
- MSBuild
- MSDeploy
- TFS API

Additionally, [TFS 2013 introduced a new feature](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2014/08/22/Separate-TFS-Build-Server-Output-into-Different-Folders.aspx) that does exactly what your looking for.  Just add `/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=True` to your MSBuild arguments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When i used the default template for our solution, the build is getting drop for every project in a single release folder. Our solution has around 70 projects and all the build is dropping into a single folder. - Is it for every solution in this way? Can we have individual folder for each and every project and how? Also how can we use MS BUILD Script file with the auto build process?

Comment: Added a new TFS 2013 feature to my answer above that may solve this issue for you.  You can extend the auto build process by adding to your project file.  This post doesn't solve your problem but is an example of how to extend MSBuild - http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/

Comment: /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=True - this worked like a charm. Do you have tutorial or msdn page on all the Build arguments can be provided. Also i wanted the customize the solution build. Is there a good tutorial which can show me some examples on how can we customize the default XAML template.

Comment: Check this SO post for links to MSBuild properties - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452962/list-of-msbuild-built-in-variables  Regarding customizing your XAML build template, I don't suggest this. We typically extend MSBuild or MSDeploy instead.  Check this link for an example - http://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/

Comment: So now i am able to create the output folder for all the projects. Now i need to customerize in such a way that, i need create a folder structure as my needs. How do i do this? Is there any way in the flow or make a  MS build script and include in the flow?

Comment: I think this warrants a new question with more details.  Post a link here and I will take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35501542/2028620 - Here is the link for the new question.