# How to create custom folder from the release folder of Windows Work flow for TFS Build process?

Tags: workflow, build-process, tfsbuild

I have used the
/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=True for creating build for each and every project in my solution and now i wanted to customerize the folder structure on my needs. How can we achieve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRjG3.png)

Comment: Please provide examples of the current folder structure and what you want it to be.

Comment: I have updated the image, which shows the structure i would require. Also how do we use a batch file in the windows work flow?

Comment: If you are using TFS 2013 or later there are a couple of options to run PowerShell scripts before/after build or before/after tests.

Comment: I have never used powershell. There is any link how can i use the power shell with TFS 2013? Also how do i achieve the structure which i have shown above.

Comment: Answer added with details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XAML build, you can customize Binaries folder in TFS Team Build by modifying the build process template. Adding CreateDirectory Activity and FindMatchingFiles activity are necessary, following [this](https://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build/) blog for more details.

If you use the new build system, that will be much easier to manage artifacts. With task [Publish Build Artifacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts), you can specify contents in the task, also you can add as many Publish Build Artifacts task as you want to manage artifacts. More details, check http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can extend your build definition with a PowerShell script at different points within the build:

- Pre-build
- Post-build
- Pre-test
- Post-test

[image]

Note I am using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml template.  This is the build template that comes with TFS 2013.