# Conditional dependency in nuget

Tags: dependencies, nuget

I have a tool which I want to deliver via nuget. I'm not very familiar with it, but what I read so far is that you can define dependencies with conditions. Can the condition also be a environment variable?

I found this here:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452'" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

What are there for other "variables" in like in the example above the `TargetFramework`?

There are also two dependencies which contains what I need, how can I say that I need one of them and not both? And how can I define which I want if nothing is installed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Environment Variable in Condition:

> Use a `Condition` attribute on a property to set the value only if the
>   property has no value. For example, the following code sets the
>   `ToolsPath` property to c:\tools only if the `ToolsPath` environment
>   variable is not set:
>
> `<ToolsPath Condition="'$(TOOLSPATH)' == ''">c:\tools</ToolsPath>`

Source: [How to: Use environment variables in a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2019)

List of all MSBuild build-in properties can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453023/7225096