# MSBuild: how do I detect a project's language (C# or F#) in an MSBuild variable / function?

Tags: c#, f#, msbuild

We have a shared `.props` file throughout a large .NET solution (OSS project) that ships primarily C# libraries with some F# APIs built on top of them. I want to globally set the C# version through the `LangVersion` property to use C# 10.0 or 11.0, but when I do this it breaks compilation of my F# projects that also depend on the same `.props` file.

Using separate `.props` files for each isn't a great option as that `.props` file is also what's responsible for populating version / package metadata and we want to keep that in one place in order to eliminate duplicative-type errors.

Therefore, what I'm trying to do is use a conditional property inside our `.props` file that looks like this:

```xml
  <!-- Set the language version for C# if we're not inside an F# project -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Language)' == 'CSharp' ">
         <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

However, I'm not sure what the right variable / output is to check this. I've gone through the lists mentioned in [List of MSBuild built-in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452962/list-of-msbuild-built-in-variables) and have not been able to find it there.

Comment: Looks like there is a `Language` property but I can't tell if this has made it into a current version of MSBuild or what its values are https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2101

Comment: `Language` property is set by `Microsoft.<languageName>.targets` which is imported after `Directory.Build.props` and after project file. It can be used, but only in targets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but perhaps:

```xml
Condition=" '$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.csproj' "
```

Taking `MSBuildProjectExtension` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022)

Comment: that's a good idea - I'll give that a try

Comment: @Aaronontheweb great! I could have used this a bunch of times myself, but in the end I usually cheat and just go with `latest` plus a `global.json` that sets the min SDK version to something *that has* the language version I want

Answer (score 3):

The `Language` property is *supposed* to exist for this purpose. I know C# and VB do, and we set it in the WiX Toolset.

I've also used a trick for language-specific `.props` by adding the following to the bottom of `Directory.Build.props`

```
<Import Project="Directory$(MSBuildProjectExtension).props"
        Condition=" Exists('Directory$(MSBuildProjectExtension).props') " />
```

Then I add any C# specific content to `Directory.csproj.props` next to the `Directory.Build.props` as needed. It scales quite nicely.